# Remove bad coordinates - Shortest path algorithm

Tags: c, sorting, a-star

I have a question. If I have two columns X, Y. They holds coordinates like x = 3, y = 8.

Sometimes there are multiple coordinates of same values like

```
X = 4, Y = 7
X = 5, Y = 8 <- Remove this 
X = 6, Y = 9 <- Remove this 
X = 4, Y = 7 <- Dead end. Remove this
X = 3, Y = 2
X = 2, Y = 2
X = 1, Y = 2
```

How can I remove bad coordinates that cause deadline ends? They X and Y list are C int arrays.

I have made the A* algorithm and now i need to make sure that the path is optimal.

First of all. I first need to know which coordinates I need to remove. Is there a method for that too?

One idea is to delete everything between two identical coordinates. Is that a smart strategy?

**Edit:**

Some of these coordinates are unuseful. Some of them are duplicated.

```
x = 8, y = 13 <- Starting
x = 8, y = 12
x = 8, y = 11
x = 8, y = 10
x = 8, y = 11
x = 7, y = 11
x = 6, y = 11
x = 6, y = 10
x = 5, y = 10
x = 5, y = 11
x = 5, y = 12
x = 6, y = 12
x = 7, y = 12
x = 7, y = 11
x = 6, y = 11
x = 6, y = 10
x = 5, y = 10
x = 5, y = 11
x = 5, y = 12
x = 5, y = 13
x = 4, y = 13
x = 3, y = 13
x = 3, y = 12
x = 3, y = 11
x = 3, y = 10
x = 2, y = 10
x = 1, y = 10
x = 1, y = 9
x = 1, y = 8
x = 1, y = 7
x = 2, y = 7
x = 2, y = 6
x = 2, y = 5
x = 2, y = 4
x = 3, y = 4
x = 4, y = 4
x = 5, y = 4
x = 5, y = 5
x = 4, y = 5
x = 4, y = 4
x = 5, y = 4
x = 5, y = 5
x = 5, y = 6
x = 4, y = 6
x = 4, y = 5
x = 4, y = 4
x = 3, y = 4
x = 3, y = 3
x = 3, y = 2
x = 4, y = 2
x = 5, y = 2
x = 6, y = 2
x = 6, y = 1 <- Goal
```

An idea I got now is that if I remove ONE coordinate, and then loop throug the rest of the coordinates. Then I can determine if the path is complete. But that would take long time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208470/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-martensson-remove-bad-coordinates-shortest-pa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

Have a look at CControl library.
https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl

Working example here https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Documents/Examples/Algorithms/A-Star/Astar.txt